# After Installing El Capitan I Will be Logged Out Frequently

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, memory

- MacPro late 2009 with 3 monitors. OSX 10.11.1
- Will run great on 1 monitor without screen/system freeze or logouts. At times it is an instant logout, other times, the primary monitor freezes, or is filled with weird graphics. NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 512 MB
- Began with 12 G Ram and upgraded to 24 after having problems with El Capitan. Suspected OS memory leak.
- Then did full erase and OS install, but before restoring my data, created new user and used Safari to test. On each monitor, a Safari tab streaming news videos. Ran for hours, but when I started using the system, it had video problems and locked up or logged out. Don't remember which.
- Then restored all my backup data and settings.
- Activity Monitor shows full 24 G installed, but the Memory Used and Cached Files never go above 12 G
- TechTools 8, all test pass. Memory, video, temperature, fans etc.
- Apple Care 2nd level tried to no avail.
- System performed flawlessly until El Capitan install
- System now is totally unreliable.
  I installed 10.11.2 yesterday and am hopeful that fixed it for me as it has many others. I'll update.
- It appears that 10.11.2 has fixed it. This was the first time I had an update go bad, thankfully. Communication would go a long way, but results are always appreciated. I still feel they (Apple) are the best horse in the race. BTW here is the Apple Support thread on this; https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7252069?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Everything you say would make me suspect overheat or underpower [GPU or PSU fail, especially pushing 3 screens from a GT120] **except** for the term 'logout'. Do you literally mean it logs you out & presents you with the user login screen again, or do you actually mean it crashes/reboots? If it's a true logout, then I'd try setting up a new admin user & test it under that.

Comment: Yes, I'm presented with the Login screen. I forgot to mention that Apple support had me add another user. The new user also gets logged out. Also when I had reloaded and before any of my data was reloaded, I exercised the system. I opened Safari, (normally I use Chrome) by opening a tab on each monitor and playing a news video. It eventually logged out.

Answer (score 2):

From 
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21782:

> **OS X El Capitan: Set your Mac to log out when not in use**
>
> You can set your Mac to automatically log out the current user after a
>   set period of inactivity. This helps ensure that your information is
>   secure when your Mac is unattended.
>
> - Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General.
> - Click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter an administrator name and password.
> - Click Advanced.
> - Select “Log out after... minutes of inactivity.”
> - Set the amount of time before the user is automatically logged out.